# Использование шаблонной системы Django

Tags: django

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли использовать (если да, то как) в своем cgi-скрипте шаблонную систему Django. Сам фреймворк установлен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. Можете. Причём где угодно:

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.configure()
>>> t = Template(u'Меня зовут {{ my_name }}.')
>>> c = Context({'my_name': 'SkyFox'})
>>> t.render(c)
u'Меня зовут SkyFox.'
```

В официальной документации это тоже описано: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#configuring-the-template-system-in-standalone-mode, но, правда, сложно найти.

Answer (score 1):

да. ты просто в urls пишешь что тебе надо вернуть файл с разширением cgi, и указываешь вьюху в которой рендришь все что тебе надо. например что-то в таком духе:
urlpatterns = patterns('search.views',

```
url(r'^my.js$','my_js',name="my_js"),
)

def my_js(request):
    return render_to_response('search/my.js',{
            'metros':Metro.objects.filter(type=MetroType[0][0]).distinct(),
            'towns':BaseModel.objects.values('town').distinct().order_by('town') ,
             } ,mimetype="application/x-javascript")
```